How to switch between parent classes during child instantiation?
I'm trying to make a custom class CsvFrame that is a dataframe made either with pandas or polars.
For that I made the code below:
class CsvFrame:
    def __init__(self, engine, *args, **kwargs):
        if engine == 'polars':
            import polars as pl
            pl.DataFrame.__init__(pl.read_csv(*args, **kwargs))

        if engine == 'pandas':
            import pandas as pd
            pd.DataFrame.__init__(pd.read_csv(*args, **kwargs))

Now when I instantiante an object, there are two problems:

there is no HTML represention of the dataframe in VS Code-Jupyter
none of the methods or attributes of a dataframe are available

import io

input_text = '''
col1,col2
A,1
B,2
'''

cfr = CsvFrame('polars', io.StringIO(input_text))

# problem 1
cfr # <__main__.CsvFrame at 0x1fd721f32c0>

# problem 2
cfr.melt()
AttributeError: 'CsvFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'

Can you help me fix that?

You don't have any parent classes here. Seems like you just want a factory function, not sure why it's a class at all.

Thank you @jonrsharpe for the reply. I actually need a class and when I try class CsvFrame(pd.DataFrame, pl.DataFrame), I get AttributeError: 'CsvFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'. I don't think anyways it's a good idea to inherit from both at the same time because they have common methods names like melt(). That's why I opened a question and see if someone can help. Is there a technique to achieve what I'm looking for ?

not a proper answer, rather a workaround, but you can have an attribute pandas and an attribute polar, and you would do cfr.pd.melt()

Thank you @seb. Your suggestion is nice but I hope someone will show me how to do cfr.melt().

Why do you need a class? With a factory function you can get an actual instance of pd.DataFrame or pl.DataFrame, with all the methods available to the chosen class.

@blhsing, I didn't mention it but the reason why I need a class is that I will add some extra methods and attributes in addition to the ones from polars and pandas. Do you think this is possible ? I'm really open to any suggestion you guys can offer.

You can use a factory function that returns an instance of a subclass of either polars.DataFrame or pandas.DataFrame based on the given engine:
def CsvFrame(engine, *args, **kwargs):
    if engine == 'polars':
        from polars import DataFrame, read_csv
    elif engine == 'pandas':
        from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Unsupported engine {engine}')

    class _CsvFrame(DataFrame):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            return read_csv(*args, **kwargs)
        # more methods can be added here

    return _CsvFrame(*args, **kwargs)

...

cfr = CsvFrame('polars', io.StringIO(input_text))
cfr.melt()

Alternatively, you can make the data frame returned by read_csv of the chosen engine an instance attribute of your CsvFrame class, which acts as a proxy object to the data frame by delegating attribute lookups to it through the __getattr__ method:
class CsvFrame:
    def __init__(self, engine, *args, **kwargs):
        if engine == 'polars':
            from polars import read_csv
        elif engine == 'pandas':
            from pandas import read_csv
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Unsupported engine {engine}')
        self.df = read_csv(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.df, name)

...

cfr = CsvFrame('polars', io.StringIO(input_text))
cfr.melt()


Thank you @blhsing. Can you confirm that there is no way CsvFrame("polars", io.StringIO(input_text)).melt() (I mean cfr = CsvFrame() ; cfr.melt()) would be possible using python ?

I've added an alternative solution that will do just that then.
